# Exe made with pyinstaller does not works

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyinstaller

I had made a simple speech recognition program and tried to make exe out it with the help of Pyinstaller , now when i run that exe on my machine it works fine and prints the recognized audio from mic but when I run this on another machine as I ran it upon ***win10 Lenovo IdeaPad 330 ***, the program runs but does not print the recognized audio and keeps on looping, even though I have given permission for mic on windows and when program makes use of mic the small icon in the taskbar too pop-ups .
Now summary is that exe made on my machine does not work on others and why?
And I think a thread could be possible duplicate as my problem like specifically related to modules 
Any solution?

here is the code

```
import speech_recognition
recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()


def listen():
   with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
      print('i m hearing !')
      recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
      try:
         audio = recognizer.listen(
         source=source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=4)
      except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
         pass

   try:
      print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
      return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
   except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
      pass
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   while True:
      user=str(listen())
      if user in ['exit','close','goodbye']:
         print('okay goodbye!')
         exit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep on looping"? You are catching your exceptions but doesn't print anything inside it. Replace `pass` with some print statement and put the output here.

Comment: Hey I checked the exe after adding the exception to print , so the error is `local variable 'audio' referenced before assignment` on the mentioned machine . Now I think this sort of  error occurs when there is no mic , isn't it ? But as per my mentioned machine configuration the exe makes use of mic . So what could be the possible solution ? And @M.R.    please do check this program exe with pyinstaller on your machine too , this might clarify .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no Mic the `speech_recognition.Microphone()` would raise and `OSError` exception, so you need to catch it. I suggest you create a function to return the `source` if there is a mic and then use it on another function to read the commands. Something like this:

```
import speech_recognition
recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()


def get_mic():
   try:
      source = speech_recognition.Microphone()
      return source
   except OSError:
      return None


def listen(source):
   with source as src:
      print('i m hearing !')
      recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(src)
      try:
         audio = recognizer.listen(
             source=src, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=4)
      except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
         print("speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError")
         return

      try:
         result = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
         return str(result)
      except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
         print("speech_recognition.UnknownValueError")
         return
      except Exception as e:
         print("Other Exception:", e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   source = get_mic()
   if not source:
      print("No Mic Device Found!")
      exit()
   while True:
      user = listen(source)
      if user in ['exit', 'close', 'goodbye']:
         print('okay goodbye!')
         exit()
      else:
         print(user)
```

And finally, run `pyinstaller -F script.py` to generate your executable.

Comment: Hey @M.R. thanks for your reply , so i followed your instruction and when i ran the exe of it on the mentioned machine , there isn't any message with **No Mic Device Found!*** , but each time I get `None` as output that means i was wrong about the mic , and I hope `None` occurs when  there is no input in the mic . But i have tried troubleshooting as well as set up mic on that machine , nothing seems to work . Hey please try  to make exe and check this code on your machine , this  might will be helpful !

Comment: I have tested above code on two machines and when there is no mic (you can try it by yourself with removing or disabling it), it would say the **No Mic**. It seems that your target machine has another problem rather not having a mic. What do you get on console (I've edited the post and put the print on all exceptions)

Comment: Thank again man! with above code i was able to rectify the problem , actually it was machine configuration issue and the problem was that this exe was not permitted for mic from settings and sometimes crotana blocked the mic for other application so i had to close that too. Thank you so much for your valuable time !!